# Is there a tool for finding the Char code of a character?

Tags: vb.net, character-encoding, char, special-characters

I am trying to write a VB function to strip unwanted characters from a string. It is for generating a 'clean' url from data that has been inputted into a CMS. Someone has copied and pasted from a Word document and so there appears to be an mdash or ndash in the product title. This results in ─ appearing instead of -

I have tried a Replace(text, Chr(196), Chr(45)) but it isn't working so it can't be 196. Is there a tool or something where I can copy this character and paste it into the tool and it will tell me what char code it is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [here](http://www.atm.ox.ac.uk/user/iwi/charmap.html) or [here](http://www.tedmontgomery.com/tutorial/altchrc.html). From 2nd link I can see that your char is alt150

Answer (score 3):

You can make your program write out the Character Code using the finction Asc()

`Response.write Asc("-")` would write out

> 45

for example.

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling there would be a function for it.